# Can't INSERT into mysql DB using php

Tags: php, mysql, insert

We're doing a website project using PHP and MySQL for Uni and while everything works perfectly on my friend's computer, mine just won't add data to the db through PHP. The code is the same, the DB is also the same (exported), the only difference is he's on mac and using MAMP and I'm on Windows 7 and using WAMP. I can add data through phpMyAdmin and edit and delete through the code. I just reinstalled WAMP entirely, localhost has all rights.

Here's one of the codes that won't work :

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'project');
session_start();
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Paris');
$auteur = $_SESSION['user'];
$texte = nl2br(addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['texte'])));
$date = date('l jS \of F Y');
$type = $_POST['type'];

if ($type == 'article'){
  $titre = addslashes(htmlspecialchars($_POST['titre']));
  $categorie = $_POST['genre'];
  $description = mb_strimwidth($texte, 0, 500,'');
  if (!empty($texte)){
    if (!empty($titre)){
      $query = "INSERT INTO articles VALUES ('', '$auteur', '$texte', '$date', '$description', '$titre', '$categorie')";
      $result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Erreur SQL : '.mysqli_error());
    else {
     echo "<script>alert('Can't publish an article without a title!');  </script>";
    }
  } else {
 echo "<script>alert('Can't publish an article without text!');</script>";
}
?>
```

While this works perfectly fine :

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'project');
session_start();
if (!$db){
    die("Our servers seem to be down. Sorry!");
}

$pseudo = $_SESSION['user'];
$newusername = $_POST['pseudo'];
$newmail = $_POST['mail'];
$newpass = $_POST['password'];
$confpass = $_POST['confpassword'];
$query = "SELECT id FROM utilisateurs WHERE pseudo = '$pseudo'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$id = $row['id'];


if (!empty($newusername)){
    $query = "UPDATE utilisateurs SET pseudo='$newusername' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
if (!empty($newmail)){
    $query = "UPDATE utilisateurs SET mail='$newmail' WHERE id='$id'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
}
if (!empty($newpass)){
    if(!empty($confpass)){
        if ($newpass == $confpass){
            $query = "UPDATE utilisateurs SET mdp='$newpass' WHERE id='$id'";
            $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
        } else {
            echo "<script>alert('The confirmation is different from the password');</script>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Please confirm the password');</script>";
    }
}
echo "<script>alert('The changes have been made.');</script>";
?>
```

My configuration : 
[Windows configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idqqM.png)

His configuration : 
[Mac configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYJ5V.jpg)

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: Do you get an error or warning?